# How to describe Dependency Injection using UML diagrams?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, cqrs, mediatr, mediator

I'm trying to create a UML diagram showing the Mediator and CQRS patterns implemented in ASP.NET Core using the MediatR library.

This is what I've come up with so far:

[image: UML diagram]

The use of "..." indicates implementation details, not relevant to the example.

- The **IRequest**, **IRequestHandler**, and **IMediator** interfaces are part of MediatR.
- The **Response**, **Query**, **Handler**, and **QueryInvoker** classes are created by the user.

I'm not sure how to properly describe dependency injections in UML.

Comment: DI cannot be represented with class diagrams. DI is just a way of implementing aggregate relations and class diagrams don't care about such technical details.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride thanks for the reply. This is for my thesis, and I would really like to add a UML diagram showing how these two patterns were implemented using MediatR. I can only find really high-level depictions of MediatR online, and nothing with UML. Do you have any recommendation for how to "correctly" or "incorrectly" depict this using UML?

Comment: For MediatoR I'd use a class diagram like you have and an additional sequence diagram showing how a concrete query is dispatched, then forwarded to correct handler and how the response is returned to the entry point where the query was dispatched. If I'd really wanna mangle DI into all that then I would add to the class diagram: 1) a relation from the handler to the injected service interface and 2) a relation from the service implementor to that interface. [...]

Comment: [...] In the sequence diagram I would squeeze a "DI" actor between the two actors "handler" and "service" to show how the service instance is retrieved from the DI and then used by the handler. This wouldn't be 100% technically correct (unless you actually resolve the service interface inside the handler's ctor), but close enough, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UML class diagram from [Chapter 1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/122) of (my book) [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl):

[image: Figure 1.10 Relationship between the collaborators of the Hello DI! application]

In this example, an implementation of `IMessageWriter` (the `ConsoleMessageWriter`) is injected into the `Salutation` class. This, however, isn't shown in the diagram itself. That's because in UML class diagrams you don't represent the fact that the `ConsoleMessageWriter` implementation is injected into `Salutation` because, from perspective of `Salutation`, there is no relationship between the two. Only design-time relationships are shown in class diagrams. The relationship is between `Salutation` and `IMessageWriter`, which is what is represented in the UML class diagram. This is why the figure's annotations note that:

> *"In effect, Salutation uses ConsoleMessageWriter, although this indirect usage isn't shown."*

To show the relationship between the concrete `ConsoleMessageWriter` and its `Salutation` consumer, you can use a UML sequence diagram. Unfortunately, there are no sequence diagrams in chapter 1 of the book. So instead, here's an example of such diagram from [chapter 3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-3/21) (note that this chapter is behind a pay wall but you'll get a few minutes access):

[image: Figure 3.4 Sequence diagram showing the interaction between elements involved in DI in the e-commerce application that we build in this chapter]

This diagram describes the interaction between elements involved in DI in the e-commerce application that we build in that chapter, and it shows how the `HomeController` communicates with the `ProductService` implementation. While at design time `HomeController` only knows of the `IProductService` abstraction, the sequence diagram describes the runtime behavior rather than the design time relationships, which is why there is no notion of the `IProductService` abstraction, but solely the `ProductService` implementation.